# Web Server Block libwww-perl requests

Tags: python, perl, web-scraping, block, http-status-code-403

I have web scraping script (Perl language) in the first time it works perfectly but after ~ 3500 ( GET request ) server return 403 error ( Forbidden | not ip banned ) but when use the same script in ( python language ) i find the same problem work but after ~ 3500 requests i get 403 ( retrun to work after 24 heures ) i   don't know what is the problem and how i can fix it

i read about libwww-perl :

https://cloudkul.com/blog/block-libwww-perl-attack-in-apache-web-server/

Comment: How do you know it's not just banning your IP address?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the operator of the site? Do you have their permission to scrape their site?

Comment: @melpomene I can send requset from burp suite

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking why you get a different error message after you're blocked for having sent 3500 requests? Why do you think it matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`agent` method provided by `LWP::UserAgent`](https://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent#agent) to change "user agent identification string".

It **should** solve blocking based on client identification string.
It **will not** solve blocking based on abusive behavior.

`perldoc LWP::UserAgent`

> **agent**
>
> ```
>   my $agent = $ua->agent;
>   $ua->agent('Checkbot/0.4 ');    # append the default to the end
>   $ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');
>   $ua->agent("");                 # don't identify
> ```
>
> Get/set the product token that is used to identify the user agent on the network. The agent value is sent as the `User-Agent` header in the requests.
>
> The default is a string of the form `libwww-perl/#.###`, where `#.###` is substituted with the version number of this library.
>
> If the provided string ends with space, the default `libwww-perl/#.###` string is appended to it.
>
> The user agent string should be one or more simple product identifiers with an optional version number separated by the `/` character.